# Retrieving changes made by each user on a specific google doc

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have the following code (from `Google Doc Api` resources) to fetch changes from google drive. However, I want to retrieve the changes made by each user on a specific google doc. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
var _driveService = GetDriveServiceInstance();

var requestxx = _driveService.Changes.GetStartPageToken();
var response = requestxx.Execute();
var savedStartPageToken = response.StartPageTokenValue;

// Begin with our last saved start token for this user or the
// current token from GetStartPageToken()
string pageToken = savedStartPageToken;
while (pageToken != null)
{
    var request = _driveService.Changes.List(pageToken);
    request.Spaces = "drive";

    var changes = request.Execute();
    foreach (var change in changes.Changes)
    {

        // Process change
        Console.WriteLine("Change found for file: " + change.FileId);
    }
    if (changes.NewStartPageToken != null)
    {
        // Last page, save this token for the next polling interval
        savedStartPageToken = changes.NewStartPageToken;
    }
    pageToken = changes.NextPageToken;
}
```

Comment: Would calling `Revisions.list` of the file, getting all revisions id's and then getting `lastModifyingUser` for each revision id be a valid workaround? Or you specifically want `Changes`?

Comment: @Iamblichus thanks for the comment. If I am not mistaken, in a single revision recorded, there might be multiple changes by multiple users, and `lastModifyingUser` will give me the user who did the last change. I wonder if there is a way to know how many changes were made by each user. As far as I see, there is no way, although these changes can be accessed when viewed the revision history in Google Docs. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best way would be using [Google Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity), which can provide more information on changes made to specific files. By calling [activity.query](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/query) you can get all past activity from a certain file, including information on the user that's behind each activity. Using this response, you could count the number of changes made by each user.

Another way, albeit incomplete, would be getting the [list of Revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list) of the file and then getting `lastModifyingUser` from each revision. As you said, though, a revision might include many changes, so the retrieved data could be incomplete.

Also, if you consider it would be useful for Drive API to provide that level of detail regarding changes made to files, you could [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/components/191650) in Issue Tracker.

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this only available for v2 (and not for v3)?

Comment: @renakre I am not sure I understand your question. Yes, Drive Activity API only has v1 and v2. It is a different API than Drive API, with its own calls and resources.

Comment: I understand now, thanks! I wonder if there is an example code to retrieve activities from a Google Doc? As far as see, such an example is hard to find, especially for c#.

Comment: @renakre I seriously doubt such an example exists, let alone in c#!. I'd tell you to provide "itemName": "items/{document_id}" in the request body. This will retrieve all past activity in the response field `activities`, whose values is an array of [activities](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/driveactivity#DriveActivity) that contains information on `actors` (the user or account that made the activity), `actions` (information about the activity itself) and `targets` (the file or drive that is modified).